# Как узнать девайс клиента?

Tags: javascript

Как узнать с какого устройства сидит клиент? то бишь Desktop, mobile, Tablet и т.д.

Пробовал либу UaParser но там не получаю такого.

Comment: Try to study this: https://www.developershome.com/wap/detection/

Answer (score 1):

Если Вам нужно получить ответ на вопрос "Это сенсорный экран?", то вот

```
function isTouchDevice() {
    try {
        document.createEvent('TouchEvent'); // Как бы имитируем событие Touch
        return true; // Если ошибки не случилось, то true
    }
    catch(e) {
        return false; // Если ошибка — false
    }
}
```

А вот узнать mobile это или tablet, (Desktop / Note) могу только посоветовать грубо вычислить по размеру экрана.

```
screen.width  // <-- Ширина экрана
screen.heigth // <-- Высота экрана (просто для полной картины)
```

Да, я конечно понимаю, что по ширине можно легко ошибиться, но ничего не поделаешь.

(Буду рад, если кто-то даст ссылку на нормальный сервис).

Comment: Как вариант. Спасибо.

Comment: В принципе, логика `isTouchDevice() ? (aspectRatio > 1 ? 'tablet' : 'phone') : 'desktop'` может быть вполне рабочей, если бы еще и поворот как-то проверять при наличии тачскрина - но как это сделать, хз... (через `window.screen.orientation.type` не вариант, а других способов я не знаю)